# SQL - return rows in partition based on max value

Tags: sql, postgresql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-partitioning

I have below dataset with comments which row must be returned.

```
INSERT INTO rates
  (country,kg_from,kg_to,value)
VALUES
  --('pl', '0', '5', '2.5'),
  --('pl', '5', '10', '4.5'),
  --('pl', '10', '15', '6'),
  --('pl', '15', '20', '8'), -- return this row
  --('de', '0', '5', '1.5'),
  --('de', '5', '10', '1.5'),
  --('de', '10', '15', '1.5'),
  --('de', '15', '45', '1.5'),  -- return this row
  --('cz', '0', '5', '5'),
  --('cz', '5', '10', '5'),
  --('cz', '10', '15', '6'),
  --('cz', '15', '30', '4') -- return this row
```

Logic is: return value for max kg_to within partition of each country.

Current working code:

```
select t.country, t.kg_to, t.value
from rates t
inner join (select country, max(t2.kg_to) as max_kg
                      from rates t2
                      group by 1) t2 on t.country = t2.country
WHERE t.kg_to = t2.max_kg;
enter code here
```

Question:

1. Shorter code would be better, any ideas on how to improve it?

Comment: Postgres and Snowflake are different SQL products.  Which are you really using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (t.country) r.*
from rates r
order by t.country, kg_to desc;
```

Or window functions:

```
select r.*
from (select r.*,
             row_number() over (partition by country order by kg_to desc) as seqnum
      from rates r
     ) r
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note:  I also don't see how your code could be retrieving duplicates, unless you have duplicate maximum values for a country in your table.

Answer (score 5):

For Snowflake, you can also avoid the sub-query on the window function and simply use the QUALIFY function:

```
select r.*
from rates r
QUALIFY row_number() over (partition by country order by kg_to desc) = 1;
```

Comment: Clean cut. Unfortunately there is no QUALIFY clause in Postgresql nor window functions are allowed in WHERE.

Comment: @Stefanov.sm OP has tagged Snowflake, though.  So, I thought I'd share.

Comment: Sure. It's elegant.

Comment: Reason for tagging postgre/snowflake is that my case had to be delt on both.

Answer (score 1):

You need distinct on (t.country) in order to have one record per country. `order by` determines which one record to pick per country.

```sql
select distinct on (country)
    country, kg_to, value
 from rates
 order by country, kg_to desc;
```

Comment: As a note, this syntax does not work with Snowflake.